# Gradual switch from Maven to SBT

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, sbt

Currently all our project builds with Maven on Windows. We were not successful with making incrementally compiled code to work in run time (50% of the cases it was failing with some kind of error), so to benefit from warm compiler and (maybe?) properly working incremental compilation we think about moving to SBT. However currently I have only one sprint to work on it, and I'm afraid to put all the eggs in a single basket and try to migrate whole project in a sprint. I need to find a way to make this change gradual, so I could advance one module at a time. So here are the main questions:

- How can I include SBT modules in Maven build (or maybe vise versa, having my "parent" in SBT, yet part of the modules still building with Maven)?
- How can we still benefit from IDE support (currently IntelliJ 13), like updated indices on changes in pom / Build.scala, task & goals invocation and so on?

Any advises on subject are highly appreciated.

Comment: you will need some sort of plugin for this - either on sbt or maven side. a quick google search finds https://github.com/shivawu/sbt-maven-plugin and https://github.com/sbt/sbt-pom-reader

Comment: Incremental compilation should be a matter of the compiler. I don't think SBT will help, though best of luck if you try.
To the best of my knowledge, you will lose IDE support.
I'd recommend having separate projects for SBT and Maven, and depending on them via the normal maven repository mechanism (you can add the local maven repository as an SBT resolver). You'll still need two different build commands, but projects from one can depend on the other which is the important thing.

Comment: @Imm Regarding the incremental compilation - yes, we might not win anything yet this is another reason for gradual change, so we'll make one module working with sbt and then decide according the performance whether we should advance. We did think about the option of having separated projects, yet it's a bit tricky, because we have one big and one small module on the server side, working on both of them with connection only via .m2 will not be convenient, and migrating both is still a big risk.

Comment: Those plugins' descriptions look promising, but they seem to have "half life" state. If someone would share his experience using them that could be a bit reassuring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually we did the switch and don't regret it. Writing SBT tasks is easier, because it's plain Scala. <strike>Incremental compilation works now (used to fail in Maven with `java.lang.InternalError: Enclosing method not found` when deployed to JBoss) and build time is significantly faster. Unfortunately we did not find a way to make a gradual switch, so we had to take the risk.</strike>  Incremental compiled jars still didn't work, yet Typesafe are about to fix this issue in 2.11.6